# Adding a null in a List<T> index: C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I have a small issue with providing user feedback.

My solution is caked up into many layers (repositories, services, etc.). I would like to be able to propagate up to the top-most layer with valuable information should there be an issue with pulling data in any of the layers.

I have to loop through an IEnumerable of database objects and map each (using AutoMapper) into POCO objects. In case there is an issue/exception with mapping a certain object, I want to note this and not affect the whole list. So I thought it would be best to catch the exception and add a null (or only set a single relevant property) in place of that object that caused the issue. That way we can do a check on another layer and know that there was an issue with some items.

Is this considered good practice? Am I violating any fundamental programming principle?

```
foreach (var tranch in tranches)
{
    try
    {
        //add option tranch to list
        tranchList.Add(Extensions.Map<Tranch, TranchVm>(tranch));
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        //if there is an issue with mapping an item, add the name of it and leave all other fields null
        response.Status = "warning";
        tranchList.Add(new TranchVm() { Description = tranch.Description });
    }
}
//check if the current status is not a warning, then set to success if not
if (!response.Status.Equals("warning"))
{
    response.Status = "success";
}

response.Data = tranchList;
```

Comment: Well, adding a null object means you are not able to distinguish between a real null object or an error that occurred. More better suitable for this solution is to rethrow the error to the next layer and to the next layer....At the toplevel you process the error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ckruczek. This is a list from a dataset from the database, therefore we won't get a null item. If the whole list is null, the foreach() loop will not iterate at all. But you might have a good point there that would be beneficial to note for other types of datasets.

Comment: Also, `null` does not provide much information. Maybe the error is recoverable or something has to be logged/shown to user ?? Personally I'd add a "Special" Item with some erroflag set and a message what the problem was if propagating the exception isn't an option.

Comment: Thanks @Fildor. I have added the other option of setting a single relevant field in the object (please see in brackets above). This will allow me or the administrator to pinpoint the faulty item. I could add the name of the tranche in this case or it's id and then leave everything else as null.